# Java zip library which works with symlinks

Tags: java, linux, zip, libraries, symlink

I have folder with many symlinks in there and I need to zip/unzip them in way that all links will be saved.

Can any Java ZIP library make this ? Maybe libraries have special configurations for this ?

Comment: Symbolic link is just file in special format, so it should be zipped as regular file. Do you have any specific problem with that?

Comment: When i try to zip them as ussual they transforms to regular file without saving link.

Comment: How do you create your zip? Are you using zip utility?

Comment: I've tried java.util.zip, true zip and zip4j

Comment: Let's do a step back. Create file hello.txt and link in the same folder. Then create zip of this folder using command line utility. Do you see both file and link into your zip?

Comment: If I use just "zip target.zip sourceDir" then no, but if I use "zip --recurse-paths --symlinks target.zip sourceDir" then yes

Comment: Cool. Now please try to do the same using java code and if it does not work your code. Unfortunately I cannot run anything on Linux right now but I believe that you are doing something wrong there.

Comment: Seems like my code does same thing as ussual zipping without parameters.